# Create a MoPubView object in XML

Tags: android, xml, tags, mopub

where to create (in which folder) or where to find MoPubView object in XML? I tried to put this code:

```
<com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
android:id="@+id/adview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
/>
```

and where is my activity to put this code:

```
      // Declare an instance variable for your MoPubView.
      private MoPubView moPubView;
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.console);
moPubView = (MoPubView) findViewById(R.id.adview);
moPubView.setAdUnitId("9122a91cfac3482cb46607622b93d84d");
moPubView.loadAd();
moPubView.setBannerAdListener(this);
 }

  protected void onDestroy() {
    moPubView.destroy();
     super.onDestroy(); 
     }
```

Thank you , and sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0):

You put the first block of code under res/layout/activity_main.xml
The second block of code put you on MainActivity.java